# Other users on server not able to open JupyterHub

Tags: linux, centos, anaconda, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I have spent a lot of time trying out the few solutions I found online to solve this. Nothing worked.

```
Install Location:
  anaconda : /opt/anaconda

Run JupyterHub
  $ cd /opt/anaconda/  <--  I have my jupyter_config.py here
  $ jupyterhub --Spawner.cmd="/opt/anaconda/bin/jupyterhub_singleuser"
```

First I got this -

```
[W JupyterHub auth:956] Failed to open PAM session for user1: [PAM Error 14] Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session
[W JupyterHub auth:957] Disabling PAM sessions from now on.
[I JupyterHub spawner:1417] Spawning /opt/anaconda/bin/jupyterhub_singleuser --port=27699
Failed to set groups [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
[E JupyterHub user:640] Unhandled error starting user1's server: Exception occurred in preexec_fn.
```

So, I updated my config with this -

```
c.PAMAuthenticator.open_sessions = False
```

The first error disappeared but I still get this -

```
Spawning /opt/anaconda/bin/jupyterhub_singleuser --port=62001
Failed to set groups [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
[E JupyterHub user:640] Unhandled error starting user1's server: Exception occurred in preexec_fn.
[W JupyterHub web:1782] 500 GET /hub/spawn (::ffff:10.2.139.158): Error in Authenticator.pre_spawn_start: SubprocessError Exception occurred in preexec_fn.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Create a group:

```
$ sudo groupadd <groupname>
```

Add a user to a group:

```
$ sudo adduser <username> <groupname>
```

Check group members:

```
$ sudo apt install members -y
$ members <groupname>
```

[jupyterhub_config.py]

```
c.LocalAuthenticator.group_whitelist = ['<groupname>']
```

I leave you my github with a tutorial:
[Gitub/Jupyter](https://github.com/Nouvellie/ubuntu/blob/ubuntu/contents/jupyter.md)

Comment: I want to use the default PAM authentication to use host login user and password. How do I do this? I dont want to add individual user

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are running the JupyterHub process as a normal user while for multiple user setups you need it to run as superuser.